# Questions regarding rrn-writer by Robin Sloane?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning

https://github.com/robinsloan/rnn-writer

I preface this by saying I do not know much about this topic, only that I have an intense interest in it, so I'm hoping I can make my questions as clear as possible.

This writing assistant was released with full code and instructions on how to make it work.  I was halfway through this process when I was told, basically, that this could not work on a Windows PC.  Torch, specifically, either doesn't work on PC, or doesn't work very well, and I am hesitant to continue.

First of all, does anyone know if that's true?

If it is true, is it theoretically possible to recreate this in a different way that will work on Windows PCs?

If so, has anyone ever done it before, or know how to do it?

If there is a way to make Torch work on PCs, is someone willing to tell me how?

I apologize if this isn't meant for this specific area of discussion.  I just don't know where else to go with my questions that I will get any kind of helpful responses.  Even if it's just telling me where I can go for more pertinent responses, that would still be appreciated.

Thank you for any help you might be willing to give.  Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.